# Could I play online using one membership on two different consoles?

Tags: ps4

If I was to buy a PSN online membership card and activate it on my brother's PS4, could I play online on my PS4? (It's two different consoles).

Comment: Gustavo, did you post this [exact same question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290651/could-i-play-online-on-two-different-consules-with-the-same-account) again today as Gustavo Morales?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but not at the same time. The latest login will kick the user on the games older logged in device.