# Could I play online on two different consules with the same account

Tags: ps4

If I was to buy a PSN online membership card and activate it on my brother's PS4, could I play online on my PS4? (It's two different consoles).  And would all account on the ps4 that is activated play online  I have my account on there ps4 but want to know if it would allowed me to play online on mine .

Answer (score 0):

If both of the accounts are online at the same time, one will be forced-logged out. But if you're the only one playing it at the time, then yes, you are able to have your account on 2 PS4s